# Assigning a list to a slice of another and converting the indexes to a different type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

So lets say for example I had a list

```
list1 = ["George", "47", "62", "71", "Apples"]
```

Is there a way I could do something like `list2 = list1[1:4]` and convert all of those values to integers at the same time, or at least right after.

EDIT:
What I just now implemented was right after the assignment of it (so in this case right after `list2 = list1[1:4]`) I did a for loop that was formatted as the following

```
for i in range(len(list2) :
   list2[i] = int(list2[i])
```

I feel this isn't the most elegant way to do this, so I still would appreciate any input, as I have multiple lists I need to do this to so doing it this way multiple times feels... sloppy to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

For example:

```py
>>> list(map(int,['01','02','03']))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how foolproof you want to make it. The easiest way is the mapping [suggested by user1104372](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64890105/8881141). You could also use a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it).

```
list1 = ["George", "47", "62", "71", "Apples"] 
list2 = [int(i) for i in list1[1:4]]
>>>[47, 62, 71]
```

This will not work if you had a mixed list, so we have to check if the string is an integer representation:

```
list1 = ["George", "47", "62.3", "Bahamas", "71", "Apples"] 
list2 = [int(i) for i in list1[1:5] if i.isnumeric()]
>>>[47, 71]
```

Unfortunately, this excludes negative numbers. We could use [regex](https://www.regexone.com/) for more complicated parsing tasks like that:

```
import re
list1 = ["George", "+47", "62.3", "Bahamas", "-71", "Apples"] 
list2 = [int(i) for i in list1[1:5] if re.match("[-+]?\d+$", i)]
>>>[47, -71]
```

The latter could be extended to more complicated cases like "39.000" which is a representation of an integer - but this goes beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is way more information that I asked for but in a totally good way. I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to be of help. This `range(len(list2)` was my preferred style when I started with Python until I noticed that you should use either directly `for egg in eggbasket:` or, if you really need the index (which you rarely do) `for i, egg in enumerate(eggbasket):`. This makes life so much easier.